# zip command is not working as expected in java code

Tags: java, cygwin, zip

I am trying to issue a zip command through a java program on a windows machine which has cygwin installed. I am giving below cmd in java code :

zip -r C:/Folder.zip C:/Folder

It gives me error - zip error:  zip I/O error: No such file or directory,Temporary file failure (C:/zibIIBYC)

But C:/Folder exists. I m not sure what is C:/zibIIBYC?

When I try below cmd :

zip -r C:/cygwin64/Folder.zip C:/Folder

Then Folder.zip is created in C:/cygwin64, but is empty.

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: you realize that you're executing an external app, which means you have to use proper Windows paths? `C:/Folder.zip` isn't a path, it's some wonky string that LOOKS like a path, and zip won't know what do with it. `C:\Folder.zip`, is, however, a path.

Comment: but i am using cygwin in that , should it not take cmd as for linux

Comment: cygwin also doesn't use dos-style paths. it'd be `/cygdrive/c/Folder` or whatever.

Comment: @Marc ... you are right it was the "/cygdrive/c" which solved teh isse ..C:/ dont work ...thanks!! :)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but you don't need Cygwin, or any external process, to zip a directory:

```
public void zip(Path zipFile,
                Path directoryToZip)
throws IOException {
    try (final ZipOutputStream zip = new ZipOutputStream(
            new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(zipFile)))) {

        Files.walkFileTree(directoryToZip, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file,
                                             BasicFileAttributes attr)
            throws IOException {
                ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(
                    directoryToZip.relativize(file).toString());
                entry.setSize(attr.size());
                entry.setTime(attr.lastModifiedTime().toMillis());

                zip.putNextEntry(entry);
                Files.copy(file, zip);
                zip.closeEntry();

                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
        });
    }
}
```